# Difference in Rust between '&mut val' and '&mut *ref_to_val', where ref_to_val = &mut val

Tags: rust, reference, mutable

The following code does **NOT** compile (which is correct, since there can't be two mutable references to the same value `n` at the same time):

```
let mut n=5;

let p1 = &mut n;
*p1 = 10;

let p2 = &mut n;
*p2 = 20;

*p1 = 30;
```

Why, on the contrary, if I use `let p2 = &mut *p1`, instead of `let p2 = &mut n` it compiles correctly and works?

```
let mut n=5;

let p1 = &mut n;
*p1 = 10;

let p2 = &mut *p1;
*p2 = 20;

*p1 = 30;
```

I expected the second code would not compile, too. Shouldn't `n` and `*p1` be the same thing? It looks like the compiler considers them as two different variables, so that multiple mutable references are allowed, but I don't understand why.

Comment: It's best to avoid overlapping mutable references like this in general.

Comment: "there can't be two mutable references to the same value n at the same time" that's not quite correct, you cannot *use* two mutable references to the same object at the same time.

Comment: Yes @cafce25, you're right, of course, thanks.